# Cloud Custodian - AWS IAM Policies - Extract KMS Blanket Allow

Tags: aws-iam-policy, cloudcustodian

I am new to Cloud Custodian and AWS and I am trying to extract all AWS IAM Policies that have a blanket allow for KMS decryption. The filter syntax and formatting just don't make sense to me. Any advice on how to construct the filters to find all these policies?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Cloud Custodian policy written in YAML that finds all AWS IAM policies with a blanket allow for KMS decryption:

```yaml
policies:
  - name: extract-iam-policies-with-kms-decryption
    resource: iam-policy
    filters:
      - type: value
        key: PolicyDocument.Statement
        value_type: policy
        op: in
        value:
          - Effect: Allow
            Action: kms:Decrypt
            Resource: "*"
```

This policy uses the `iam-policy` resource type to target AWS IAM policies. It then applies a filter to check if the `PolicyDocument.Statement` contains a statement with an effect of "Allow", action "kms:Decrypt", and a resource value of "*". This matches the condition for a blanket allow for KMS decryption.